# Spring Boot - talking between two applications

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot

I guess this is pretty basic stuff, but couldn't find anything interesting.

Let's say that I have a large CRM/ERP Spring Boot app. I will call it "app A". It's used only internally on a company's intranet. For security reasons, it would be best if it would not be exposed to publicly.

Now, I want to build another, much smaller app, like blog or ads wall, call it "app B".  The only purpose of this app is to expose a small part of data managed by A to the public, in the form of a blog or ads wall.

Of course A uses some sort of database engine, covered with Hibernate, and has some services and so on. The tricky part is that I'd like to not use Hibernate in app B and get data only from app A, getting them remotely (they both could be deployed on the same machine with different domains), using services that A has.

In general my question is; is this is a good idea, and also, even more important, how to do that? I know about existence of Facade Pattern, I know that you could make a REST API and use json. But is there a better way? I'm not that deep into Java as I would like to be. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This is an example of what's being called "microservices". The best approach is in fact generally to just use a JSON REST API; Spring `@ResponseBody`/`@RestController` and `RestTemplate` make that sort of communication painless.

Comment: I know, but I was thinking if for example sending whole classes through different techniques, or using UDP would be better. What about securing json communication? Is it a matter or sending and checking api token, or is there any other, spring fashion, way?

Comment: Search for "Spring Security and microservices". There have been a number of talks on the subject recently.

Comment: I concur, a microservice that exposes only the data you want visible to the outer world (i.e. consumed by App B) is one of the best approaches.  You can isolate and secure it as much as you need to without having App B directly expose elements of App A

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think it is the best idea to do that. Also, in this way, we can call to third party application. Simply you can call an application from another application as follows.

Assume Your app A run-in your localhost port 5000 and app B run-in localhost port 8080.

Method in-app A

```
@GetMapping("/call_a")
public String appA(){
    return "Superb";
}
```

Method in app-B

```
@GetMapping("/call_b")
public String appB(){

    final String uri = "http://localhost:5000/call_a";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, ResponseEntity.class);

    return result;
}
```

Then you call http://localhost:8080/call_b in app B, It return the value of `Superb`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey as I can see you are trying to talk between two spring apps, the approach is shown in the above answer where they are calling the app A using a rest call.

But you can try using docker also.

and connect both apps using docker-compose.

for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  appA:
    ports: 
      - "4001:8081"
  appB:
    ports: 
      - "4002:8082"
```

you would need to add some more specs in here.....

now you can call appA from appB and aapB from appA just by their name.

and you can stop external access.